# SQL Server not listed while creating a job using SSIS package

Tags: ssis

[image: I am not able to find SQL Server under Step while creating a job. When I select type as SSIS Package and the other options per the image]

Please look into the below error which I am facing. I am trying to create a new job. While configuring the step 1 for this job I am trying to set an SSIS dtsx package under SSIS db. But it doesn't allow me to select my SQL Server Database Engine under the Server drop down. It shows an empty drop down. Please let me know what could be wrong.

Comment: Can't you just write the server name there?

Comment: Your DB Engine allow external connections?

Comment: @JamesZ can you convert your comment as an answer? That would help me mark it as an answer. Because I found your comment as the best solution. I still thank you and appreciate you! So please don't disappoint me. I would like to learn from a real Guru like you.

Answer (score 1):

When you click the Server drop down, it kicks off a network scan asking any server running the SQL Browser service if they have any SQL Server instances it can talk to. The browser service can be off and SQL Server works just fine, it just means it isn't broadcasting that it is available. Some folks have a misguided belief that, much like hiding under the covers so monsters cannot find you, not advertising that you have a SQL Server instance running you're more "secure."

But the Browser service is running. Ok, then what about firewall, networking rules and potentially user account controls - it's likely that one of those is blocking packets *somewhere.*

Answer (score 1):

In the job step configuration, you can enter a name for the step. Choose the SQL Server Integration Services Package type, enter the name of the server and select the package.

[image: Deploy and Schedule an SQL Server Integration Services SSIS Package Step by Step]

This article will help you to tackle with SSIS/SQL:
[mssqltips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9069/deploy-and-schedule-an-sql-server-integration-services-ssis-package-step-by-step/)

Answer (score -1):

I had to manually enter the SQL Server name inside the Server dropdown shown in the above screenshot  to fix the problem.

Comment: Your question was about being unable to select the server. Manually entering the server name was mentioned in comments.